# How to remove all values within square brackets, including the brackets | Swift

Tags: swift

Looking to remove everything within a strings square brackets, including the square brackets. How can this be done in Swift? The Values in the square brackets can vary.

**Sample String:**

```
[2049A30-3930Q4] The Rest of the String
```

**Desired Result:**

```
The Rest of the String
```

Comment: do you need a solution where you have more than one `[2049A30-3930Q4]` square bracket set in the string?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you could try something simple like this:

```
var sampleString = "[2049A30-3930Q4] The Rest of the String"

sampleString.removeSubrange(sampleString.startIndex..."[2049A30-3930Q4]".endIndex)
// this will also work
// sampleString.removeSubrange(sampleString.startIndex..."[0000000-000000]".endIndex)
print("----> sampleString: \(sampleString)")
```

EDIT-1: more general approach if needed.

```
if let from = sampleString.range(of: "[")?.lowerBound,
   let to = sampleString.range(of: "]")?.upperBound {
    sampleString.removeSubrange(from...to)
    print("----> sampleString: \(sampleString)")
}
```

Comment: If the values don't follow the identical, hard-coded format then this does not work. My solution works with any string between the brackets.

Comment: ok, updated my answer with a more general approach, using the same technique.

Comment: It's honestly not as elegant as my approach and still leaves the space, otherwise with my approach the same result can be accomplished in a single line.

Comment: `..leaves the space` what space? My approach does not use intermediate temp variable. Much more efficient.

Comment: Never mind, my bad on that.

Comment: I still think my solution is more simple though. No ranges to deal with. Just `String` and `String` functions.

Comment: I disagree, my approach does not add additional characters
                 to the original string to make things work, it simply cutout the unwanted part.

Comment: At the expense of using an additional line, which is ~50% more code. So I don't think it is more elegant.

Comment: my tests shows that my code is **6 times** more efficient, (0.8842 vs 6.7582) secs

Comment: 6 seconds? It doesn't even take a millisecond.

Comment: tests over 1000000 operations. Try it yourself create a for loop. Let us know your results.

Comment: You didn't state it was for 1M operations. My method is less than 2 microseconds, plenty of fast for any practical use.

Comment: Note, I'm not the OP. Maybe he/she has a large file to process. In any case my answer is much more efficient according to time tests. What results did you get?

Comment: I somehow doubt that very much. The OP didn't ask for the highest performance possible. They just asked for a way to do it. I'm over arguing about it.

Comment: ha ha, yes, but it was good fun, right? I'm sure someone will add a regex solution soon.

Comment: Not really my idea of fun, but to each their own. If top performance is needed, then I think your edited version is better, but at the expense of being less elegant and harder to learn. For most things, I'd just use mine, but it's good to have options so well played.

Answer (score 1):

Use `replacingOccurrences` with a regex

```
string.replacingOccurrences("\\[.*\\]", with: "", options: .regularExpression)
```

Answer (score 0):

This implementation is pretty universal. It removes the content between the brackets (or other desired characters) even if there are more of them.

### Implementation:

```
extension String {
    func removingSubranges(startChar: Character, endChar: Character) -> String {
        var copy = self
        copy.removeSubranges(startChar: startChar, endChar: endChar)
        return copy
    }

    mutating func removeSubranges(startChar: Character, endChar: Character) {
        var startIndex: String.Index?
        
        self
            .indices
            .reduce(into: [ClosedRange<String.Index>](), {
                if let index = startIndex {
                    if self[$1] == endChar {
                        $0.append(index...$1)
                        startIndex = nil
                    }
                } else if self[$1] == startChar {
                    startIndex = $1
                }
            })
            .reversed()
            .forEach { self.removeSubrange($0) }
    }
}
```

### Usage:

```
let sampleString = "[aaaaaa]The[bbbbb][cccc] Rest of the String [dddddddd]"
let desiredString = sampleString.removingSubranges(startChar: "[", endChar: "]")
                
assert(desiredString == "The Rest of the String ")
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `String` split function:

```
let sampleString = "[2049A30-3930Q4] The Rest of the String"
let preSplit = sampleString.replacingOccurrences(of: "] ", with: "]")
if let results = preSplit.split(separator: "]").last {
    print(results)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**Note: This solution is straight forward provided that string contains only one closing braces and it is present in the front of the desired string.**

```
let sampleString = "[2049A30-3930Q4] The Rest of the String"
let stringArray = sampleString.components(separatedBy: "]")
print(stringArray.last)
```