# How to alternate background color of records in ScrollView | SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Essentially I would like to alternate the background colors of rows in `ScrollView`, following the pattern white, gray, white, gray, etc.

How can this be done?

```
@State var posts: [Item] = []
@State var expanded = false
@State var totalRows = 0

ForEach(posts.prefix(expanded ? totalRows : 5), id: \.id) { post in
    Label {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(convertDate(post.date))
        }
        .padding(.leading, 8)
    }  icon: {}
}

.frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 35, height: 85, alignment: .leading)
.background(Color("cellColor")) //<-- Currently Setting Color Here
.cornerRadius(10)
```

**Struct Codable for JSON**

```
struct Item: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var date: String
    var name: String
    var occupation: String
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
 List { // <-- here
    ForEach(Array(posts.prefix(expanded ? totalRows : 5).enumerated()), id: \.0) { index, post in  // <-- here
         VStack {
             Label {
                 VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                     Text(convertDate(post.date))
                 }
                 .padding(.leading, 8)
             } icon: {}
         }
         .listRowBackground(index % 2 == 0 ?  Color.gray : Color.white) // <-- here
     }
 }
 .frame(width: 333, height: 444, alignment: .leading) // <-- for testing
 .cornerRadius(10)
```

If you want to use a `ScrollView` instead of a `List`, use `.background(index % 2 == 0 ?  Color.gray : Color.white)`  instead
of the `.listRowBackground(...)`

Note, with minor adjustments you can also use `.indices` instead of `.enumerated()`.

Comment: Hmm odd, I had to re-create my xcode project, I copied over all the code and now getting error `Argument type 'EnumeratedSequence<Array<Item>.SubSequence>' (aka 'EnumeratedSequence<ArraySlice<Item>>') expected to be an instance of a class or class-constrained type`. On ForEach line, the only real difference between the old and new xcode projects is I've enabled CoreData as well, any ideas?

Comment: did my answer helped in anyway? Similarly regarding your
 previsous questions at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73214814/getting-error-when-converting-date-format-error-swift/73215073
 and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73216264/how-to-remove-all-values-within-square-brackets-including-the-brackets-swift

Comment: Yes, apologies I just marked them as correct. Any idea what issue is here?

Comment: Thank you. I think when you create a new project with CoreData, it comes ready made with an example `Item`, which may clash with your `Item`.